# React native + mobx dont re render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

Iam currently building an application with react native and mobx. My problem is that the component is not re-rendered after a observable value from the store is changed. My code looks as following:

components/phoneNumberChange.js:

```
@inject('store')
@observer export class PhoneNumberChange extends React.Component{
renderPhoneInput = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Button onPress={() => this.props.store.showCountryPicker()}>
      <Text>Show picker</Text>
    </Button>
  </React.Fragment>
);

render = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <CountryCodePicker visible= {this.props.store.pickerVisible}/>
  </React.Fragment>
);
}
```

screens/loginScreen.js:

```
import { Provider } from "mobx-react";
import { store } from "stores/phoneNumberChangeStore.js";
import { PhoneNumberChange } from "components/phoneNumberChange.js";

export class LoginScreen extends React.Component{

render = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PhoneNumberChange/>
  </Provider

);

}
```

stores/phoneNumberChangeStore.js:

```
import { observable, action } from "mobx";

class PhoneNumberChangeStore {
  @observable pickerVisible;

  constructor(){
    this.hideCountryPicker();
  }
  @action hideCountryPicker = () => {
    this.pickerVisible = false;
  }
  @action showCountryPicker = () => {
    this.pickerVisible = true;
  }

}
export const store = new PhoneNumberChangeStore();
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
            {
                "legacy": true
            }
        ]
    ]
  };
};
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "main": "app/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "mobx": "^5.9.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-ui-kitten": "^3.1.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The countryCodePicker gets shown or not when the visible prop changes. This is working. but when i change a value from the store it doesnt update and gets shown. I would appreciate any help!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting your store singleton as `default` in `phoneNumberChangeStore.js`, but you are importing a named export `PhoneNumberChangeStore` in `loginScreen.js`.

Use the `default` export in `loginScreen.js` instead. The store property is also called `pickerVisible`, not `countryCodePickerVisible`.

Comment: hey, thank you for the fast answer! iam now using: export const store = new PhoneNumberChangeStore(); and import it using: import {store} from ...; its still not working. the propertys are right in my code, that was only a typo while copying the code to this thread.

Comment: @wannabe_informatiker You're welcome! Alright, please update your question to remove the typos.

Comment: @wannabe_informatiker It's hard to say what it might be. [It works for me on the web](https://codesandbox.io/s/r7rrx8wpkn).

Comment: Ouh, too bad! Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1):

**Found the solution!** I redefined render on the instance.

I changed `render = () => {..}` to `render(){ return (...); }`

cheers!